# CastError: Cast to number failed for value "undefined" (type undefined) at path "messages" MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

I'm trying to make it so I can store how many messages a member has sent in my discord server. I'm using MongoDB and `discord.js`.
Here's my profile schema :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const reqString = {
    type: String,
    required: true
}

const profileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    guildId: reqString,
    userId: reqString,
    points: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    messages: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('profiles', profileSchema)
```

And the code that should prompt when a message is sent:

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {

    const messageStuff = require('./messageCount')

    const guildId = message.guild.id
    const userId = sender.id  

    const incMessage = await messageStuff.addMSG(guildId, userId, 1)
    }
```

As posted in the title, I get the following error when a message is sent. This makes me think that it's fine with the message listener but has problems when it gets to the actual database writing.
`CastError: Cast to number failed for value "undefined" (type undefined) at path "messages"`

Comment: Can you add what exactly `messageStuff.addMSG` does?

Comment: you're sending 3 parameters to .addMSG....and you have 4 members in your Schema...what exactly do you expect for the "messages" to contain?